# How to fake being offline in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a javascript function which is supposed to behave differently when offline than online as a safeguard.  I would like to have a Jasmine unit test which tests the function in both offline and online modes - e.g.,

```
// offline
describe('When there is no connection to the internet', function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(navigator, 'onLine').and.returnValue(false);
  });

  it('offline behavior happens', function() {
    myFunction();

    expect(something).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

// online
describe('When there is a connection to the internet', function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(navigator, 'onLine').and.returnValue(true);
  });

  it('online behavior happens', function() {
    myFunction();

    expect(something).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

However, I am unable to fake the value of `navigator.onLine`.  In my `before`, I also tried:

```
navigator = {
  'onLine': false
}
```

This didn't work either.  To be thorough, I tried the same techniques above with `window.navigator.onLine` and that also didn't work.

Does anyone know how to mock being offline for a Jasmine test?

Comment: If your behavior depends on a boolean value, why not inject the value? `myFunction(onlineValue)`

Comment: Because then I need to update every single call to my method with a parameter and I don't want to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have no chance to overwrite some built in properties. Though with [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) you can reconfigure builtin properties.

## Jasmine 2.6 and newer

Since Jasmine 2.6 ([release notes](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/release_notes/2.6.0.md)) there is [`spyOnProperty()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.6/global.html#spyOnProperty).

This is how you would spy `navigator.onLine`:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    spyOnProperty(Navigator.prototype, 'onLine').and.returnValue(false);
});
```

Note that the prototype object `Navigator` is referenced, not it's instance `window.navigator`.

## Jasmine pre 2.6

### Build a facade for browser objects

With pre Jasmine 2.6 you can't spy attributes (or properties) directly.

I'd suggest to create a facade for such browser builtins using getter methods. Then you can mock those methods in your tests to return what you like.

```
const Browser = (function() {
    return {
        isOnline: function() {
            return navigator.onLine;
        }
    };
})();
```

In your code:

```
if (Browser.isOnline()) {
    // ...
}
```

In your test:

```
beforeEach(function(){
    spyOn(Browser, 'isOnline').and.returnValue(false);
});
```

### Do what `spyOnProperty()` does on your own

If you cannot upgrade from a pre 2.6 version for some reason, you could even spy manually by utilizing [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor).

```
var onlineState,
    origOnLineProp;

beforeEach(function() {
    // Remember original config
    origOnLineProp = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Navigator.prototype, "onLine");

    onlineState = true;

    // New behavior
    Object.defineProperty(Navigator.prototype, "onLine", {
        enumerable: origOnLineProp.enumerable,
        configurable: origOnLineProp.configurable,
        get: function() { return  onlineState }
    });
});

it("...", function() {
    onlineState = false;
    expect("code").toBe("correctly functioning in offline mode");
});

afterEach(function() {
    // Restore original behavior
    Object.defineProperty(Navigator.prototype, "onLine", {
        enumerable: origOnLineProp.enumerable,
        configurable: origOnLineProp.configurable,
        get: origOnLineProp.get
    });
});
```

You could even implement your own `spyOnProperty()` backport if you're desperate (that's beyond this answer though).

Comment: I ended up doing something like this a few days ago when I saw I had no answers.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but in addition was trying to detect the situation when the browser went from an *offline* state to an *online* state, in order to try reconnecting an EventSource.

The code I was trying to test was this:

```
private startOfflineWatcher(): void {
    const that = this;
    window.addEventListener('offline', () => {
        window.addEventListener('online', () => {
            that.reconnectTimeout();
        });
    });
}
```

Using `spyOnProperty(Navigator.prototype, 'onLine').and.returnValue(false);` did not work in my case, because I had to simulate the state change. However, I was able to achieve this by simply dispatching two new events to window. My working Jasmine test looks like this now:

```
it('should start reconnect when getting online after being offline', () => {
        spyOn<any>(service, 'reconnectTimeout');
        const offlineEvent = new Event('offline');
        const onlineEvent = new Event('online');

        (service as any).startOfflineWatcher();

        window.dispatchEvent(offlineEvent);
        window.dispatchEvent(onlineEvent);

        expect((service as any).reconnectTimeout).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Depending on the use case, this might be more suitable than mocking the navigator.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
window.navigator['__defineGetter__']('onLine', () => false); // false = OFFLINE

window.navigator['__defineGetter__']('onLine', () => true); // true = ONLINE
```