# How to redefine browser builtin variable to certain value to test a module?

Tags: testing, jasmine, bdd, jasmine2.0

How could I test this using Jasmine ?

```
/** Function for detecting if user uses IE-Browser */
Cemcloud.detectIE = function () {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

    var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
    if (msie > 0) {
        // IE 10 or older => return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
    }

    var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
    if (trident > 0) {
        // IE 11 => return version number
        var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
        return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
    }

    var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
    if (edge > 0) {
        // IE 12 => return version number
        return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
    }

    // other browser
    return false;
};
```

How could I test this function so if I set var msie = "MSIE ";
So that I know that it returns number ?

```
it('should be able to test function detectIE', function(){
    var Cemcloud = Cemcloud.detectIE();
    var ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36';
    var msie = 'MSIE ';
    var trident = 'Trident/';
    expect(Cemcloud).toNumber();
    expect(Cemcloud).toContain('Trident/');
});
```

I want to test if my code goes into the if else statement which means that I need to set var msie, but I don't know how to set it inside the method ?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a _simple_ facade/wrapper object with a function that just returns the value of `window.navigator.userAgent`. You can then spy on that wrapper object's function and return what you want. [See this answer on the same topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150475/how-to-fake-being-offline-in-jasmine/41224373#41224373).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fake being offline in Jasmine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150475/how-to-fake-being-offline-in-jasmine)